# How can I fetch parent document details based on the referenced document details in where condition in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have two documents like below.

```
const ClaimDetailsSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    benefitArea: String,
    gfo: String,
    productForm: String,
    type: String,
    status: String,
    claimTitle: String,
    claimId: String,
    claimName: String,
    exception: String,
    createdBy: String,
    createdByNtId: String,
    lastModifiedBy: String,
    claimType: {
        historyId: String,
        commentId: String,
        exportId: String,
        version: String,
        reason: String
    },
    Substantiations: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Substantiations' }],
    Formulaes: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Formulaes' }],
    regions: [String],
    favorites: [String],
    claimCreatedDate: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    lastModifiedDate: { type: Date }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('ClaimDetails', ClaimDetailsSchema);

const mongoose = require('mongoose'), Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const SubstantiationSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    substantiation: String
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Substantiations', SubstantiationSchema);
```

I need to fetch the ClaimDetails based on the substantiation text in the where clause.

I have tried like below, but no Luck.

```
exports.testCase = (req, res) => {
    Claimdetails.find().populate({ path: 'Substantiations', match: { substantiation: 'rel' } }).exec(function (err, claims) {
        res.send({ data: claims });
    });
};
```

Comment: does it work if you don't put the `match` condition inside populate... Does it fetch the populated data?

Comment: Yes Anthony. It is fetching. But I need ClaimDetails document based on substantiation details.

Comment: can you please post sample collection for both the documents

Comment: ClaimDetails
-------------
{
 "_id": "5b45af28216c031f7009999a",
 "Substantiations": ["5b4496f5331cb44a0cd9eaaa", "5b449702331cb44a0cd9eaab"],
 "Formulaes": ["5b4496bb331cb44a0cd9eaa8", "5b4496de331cb44a0cd9eaa9"],
 "regions": ["AP", "NA"],
 "favorites": ["manjesh.m", "rdevarap"],
 "benefitArea": "Moisturization",
 "gfo": "Beauty",
 "productForm": "Capsule,hard",
 "claimTitle": "Test project with NodeJS",
 "claimId": "CLM2018000014",
 "__v": 0
}
Sunstantiation
---------------
{"_id":"5b4496f5331cb44a0cd9eaaa","substantiation":"test data added","__v":0}

Comment: for the data you have posted `substantiation` with `match: { substantiation: 'test data added' }` works for me

Comment: Could you please post the query you used to fetch the document - Anthony

Comment: `db.collection.find().populate({ path: 'Substantiations', match: { substantiation: 'test data added' } })` what is your mongodb version?